# Reading from an array list and comparing to an input string

Tags: java, arrays, list, compare, character

Basically I have been asked to create a small letters game in which the user picks some vowels and consonants and these are added to an array list, once that has happened, we have to print out the contents of the array list e.g. it could look like this, [T,S,I,L,Y,A,R,R,A] and then we prompt the player to input what words they think they can make from the given list of characters. What I am looking for some pointers on is how to make sure the user can only use they characters and also how to compare their answer to a dictionary file. The only code I have so far is reading in my dictionary file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```java
try {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (line != null) {
        String[] wordsLine = line.split(" ");
        for (String word : wordsLine) {
            words.add(word);
        }
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Here is your board again: " + genString + "\n");
    System.out.println("Please enter your answer!\n");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

genString is my, what would be the list of characters and I have still to place the scanner in for user input.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is putting the characters from user input into some collection, then iterating over the characters of the word and checking against that collection.
Finally, if everything is kosher, look up the word in the dictionary.

```
List<Character> charsFromUser = new LinkedList<Character>();
Set<String> dictionary        = new HashSet<String>();
boolean illegalCharUsed       = false;
boolean done                  = false;
String wordFromUser           = null;

// dictionary = // fill dictionary
// charsFromUser = // get chars from user
// wordFromUser = // get word from user

for (int i = 0, l = wordFromUser.length(); i < l && !illegalCharUsed; ++i) {
    char c = wordFromUser.charAt(i);
    if (!charsFromUser.contains(c)) {
        illegalCharUsed = true;
    } else {
        charsFromUser.remove(Character.valueOf(c)); // remove this line if 
                                                    // users may reuse letters
    }
}

if (!dictionary.contains(wordFromUser)) {
    if (!illegalCharUsed && charsFromUser.isEmpty()) { // isEmpty check if users
                                                       // must use all letters
        System.out.println("well done");
    } else {
        System.out.println("you didn't use the correct characters");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("not a legal word");
}
```